# Streamlit - Cannot repeat emoji string using st.write()

Tags: python, repeat, emoji, streamlit

**Summary:**

Normally to repeat a string in python, you'd use (string * n) where n = number of times to repeat.

In Streamlit you have the ability to print emoji using corresponding shortcodes in `st.write()`.

I've been able to use `st.write(emoji1, emoji2, emoji3)` to print emoji successfully, but when I use (string *n) to repeat the emoji string, st.write prints the shortcodes as strings vs printing the actual emoji.

Is this a shortcoming on Streamlit's code, or am I missing something?

Here's the link to the app so you can see:

https://halfgingerbeard-30daysofstreamlit-emoji-frame-creator-bsodkg.streamlit.app/

**Tried/Expected:**

Using a dataframe of Streamlit-accepted emoji shortcodes as df_emoji:

```
emoji1 = st.select_slider('Select emoji 1:', options = df_emoji['shortcodes'], value=':sunglasses:')
emoji2 = st.select_slider('Select emoji 2:', options = df_emoji['shortcodes'], value=':white_check_mark:')
emoji3 = st.select_slider('Select emoji 3:', options = df_emoji['shortcodes'], value=':coffee:')

e_columns = st.number_input('Select Number of Columns:',1,10,3)

st.write(emoji1, emoji2, emoji3) # this works successfully

st.write((emoji1, emoji2, emoji3) * e_columns)[:e_columns]) # this prints out the string values of the shortcodes instead of the actual emoji
```

I'm expecting a repeating concatenated string of emoji the length of e_columns, not each shortcode in string format

e.g. ( vs ':sunglasses:')

Comment: This one worked `st.write(2 * ':sunglasses:')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you have a syntax error on your last line:

```
st.write((emoji1, emoji2, emoji3) * e_columns)[:e_columns])
#                                                         ^ unmatched
```

Add an extra open paren `(` just after `st.write`:

```
st.write(((emoji1, emoji2, emoji3) * e_columns)[:e_columns])
#       ^ here
```

---

Now, in your first call to `st.write()`, you are passing each individual shortcode as a separate parameter:

```
st.write(emoji1, emoji2, emoji3) # 3 parameters
```

However, in the second call just below it, you are passing it a single parameter - a tuple:

```
st.write(((emoji1, emoji2, emoji3) * e_columns)[:e_columns]) # just one parameter
```

Try using the unpacking operator `*` to separate out each emoji into an individual parameter:

```
st.write(*((emoji1, emoji2, emoji3) * e_columns)[:e_columns])
#        ^
```

So, if `e_columns` is 5, for example, from Python's perspective the actual function call will be

```
st.write(emoji1, emoji2, emoji3, emoji1, emoji2)
```

Comment: Thanks! My actual code had the extra paren, must have missed it when typing :)

The unpacking operator worked perfectly!